# Previous and Next row record

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have following output

```
ID   Number   Speed   LAT           LONG           DATETIME
101   AB01      15    73.066016     33.5840768     9/1/15 23:10
101   AB01      20    73.0619712    33.5871456     9/1/15 23:30
101   AB01      0     73.0722176    33.6007488     9/1/15 23:45
101   AB01      0     73.0722112    33.6007488     9/2/15 02:10
101   AB01      0     73.0722176    33.6007008     9/2/15 02:35
101   AB01      0     73.0722432    33.6007456     9/2/15 04:35
101   AB01      0     73.0721664    33.6007904     9/3/15 12:35
101   AB01      0     73.072192     33.6007488     9/3/15 13:35
101   AB01      0     73.072192     33.6007488     9/4/15 11:35
101   AB01      0     73.072192     33.6007488     9/4/15 14:35
101   AB01      1     73.072192     33.6007488     9/5/15 14:35
```

but required output are

```
ID   Number   Speed   LAT           LONG           DATETIME
101   AB01      15    73.066016     33.5840768     9/1/15 23:10
101   AB01      20    73.0619712    33.5871456     9/1/15 23:30
101   AB01      0     73.0722176    33.6007488     9/1/15 23:45   
101   AB01      0     73.072192     33.6007488     9/4/15 14:35
101   AB01      1     73.072192     33.6007488     9/5/15 14:35
```

i want to skip extra 0 speed value.if i include these 0 zero's query response time increase. 
code attempt

```
SELECT   Distinct ID,Number,Speed,LAT,LONG,DATETIME
FROM        table
group by D,Number,Speed,LAT,LONG,DATETIME
```

Comment: Please include your coding attempt.

Comment: What is your problem? What did you try? How do your recognize the records you want to filter and want to keep?

Comment: @EdwinStoteler Speed 0 mean Vehicle does't change their location.So i want location and last stop location.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`LEAD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx), [`LAG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) window functions to detect speed discontinuities (if this is what you actually want):

```
SELECT ID, Number, Speed, LAT, [LONG], [DATETIME]
FROM (
  SELECT ID, Number, Speed, LAT, [LONG], [DATETIME],
         LEAD(Speed) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Number
                           ORDER BY [DATETIME]) AS NextSpeed,
         LAG(Speed) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Number
                           ORDER BY [DATETIME]) AS PrevSpeed         
  FROM mytable) AS t
WHERE Speed <> COALESCE(NextSpeed, -1) OR Speed <> COALESCE(PrevSpeed, -1)
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/12e43/5)